# Combinatorics: $N$ couples sitting in a row, $M$ couples in the $N$ couples can't sit together.

Tags: combinatorics

> $N$ couples sitting in a row, $M$ couples in the $N$ couples can't sit together. How many ways are there to arrange the seat?

This is a variation of ménage problem, I thought I could arrange the M couples first using ménage problem's solution(https://www.math.dartmouth.edu//~doyle/docs/menage/menage/menage.html), but then it does not count ACaBcb, where $M=2$ (that is Aa, Bb) and $N=3$. Thanks!

It is not necessary that women and men alternate, **AC**aB**cb**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. By the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) we have
$$(2N)!-\binom{M}{1}\cdot\underbrace{2\binom{2N-1}{1}1!(2N-2)!}_{\text{at least one of the $M$ couples together}}+\binom{M}{2}\cdot\underbrace{2^2\binom{2N-2}{2}2!(2N-4)!}_{\text{at least two of the $M$ couples together}}-\dots$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks! Alternate till M couples right?

Comment: @kevin Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Hi Prof, from a logical point of view, isn't the complement of "At least $1$ of the $M$ couples together" equal to "None of the $M$ couples together"？ Suppose that's true, why alternate with additional terms? Thanks!

Comment: No, "at least 1 of the M couples together" means a particular couple of the M couples together multiplied by $M$. Revise the inclusion-exclusion principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: Hi Prof, thanks! Now I see that $A_i$ stands for the event that the $i^{th}$ couple sits together.

Comment: @kevin Well done!!

Comment: Thanks Prof! (-: